# Subprocess Popen to call a tasks file python which cannot able to load models in Django

Tags: python, django

I have Django app ..we have several tasks file(stored into tasks folder).
And we want to call those tasks file from views.py

Now when we call

```
p = Popen("python","./tasks/task1.py", "jobid", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
output_filename, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
```

now in task1.py

```
from app.models import Job #its throwing error
```

It cannot import Models into task1.py where I have sent job id

```
from app.models import Job\r\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'app\'\r\n
```

Folder structure

```
project
 |-app
    |-models.py
    |-views.py 
 |-tasks
    |- task1.py
```

Comment: Can you add the error trace to your question?

Comment: from app.models import Job\r\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'app\'\r\n

Comment: You have to specify the working directory with the ```cwd``` argument.